# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, laravel-5

I need print My collaborators who related with project_id in collaboration table. this is My dompdf controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use PDF;
use App\Collaboration;

class CollaboPDFController extends Controller
{
    public function getPDF($id){
        $collaborators = Collaboration::project();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('customer.customer');//,['collaborators'=>$collaborators]);
        return $pdf->stream('customer.customer');
    }
    //
}
```

this is collaboration model scope function

```
public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }
```

and this is printing blade file customer.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Test PDF</h2>
  @if($collaborators)
           @foreach( $collaborators as $collaborator)
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <img src="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->getAvatarUrl() }}" />
                             {{ $collaborator->user()->first()->username}}
                             {{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id}}

                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif

</body>
</html>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('project/{project}/getPDF','CollaboPDFController@getPDF');
```

pdf link

```
<p><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/getPDF">Collaborator Report</a></p>
```

but when I click pdf link laravel generated following error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

how can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong, url in `<a>` tag `href`, use:

```
/projects/{{$project->id}}/getPDF
instead of
/project/{{$project->id}}/getPDF
```

That's why the laravel is showing you the 404 error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh...good your solution is working but now came new error **Collaboration.php line 39:Missing argument 2 for App\Collaboration::scopeProject()**

Comment: Try to pass `$id` like this: `Collaboration::project($id)`

Comment: sucess but not printed My collaborators only print **<h2>Test PDF</h2>**

Comment: can you guess this problem

Comment: Try to use `get()` in front of `Collaborators::project()->get()`